# Kendo UI Grid: Form post on a column with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which currently uses an **ActionLink** in a column:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID)
      .Template(@<text>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", 
                                 "ManageUser", new { id= @item.ID}, null)
                </text>);
```

The above Action in our app has been changed and can now **only receive Posts**. How do I change the above code to post the **id** to the **ManageUser** controller when the link is clicked in the column?

I have tried to put a form in the column like this, but it doesn't render the form tags:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID)
      .Template(@<text>
                @Html.BeginForm("Index", "ManageUser", new {id= @item.ID})
                                {
                                    <a   "javascript to post">@item.ID</a>
                                }
                </text>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your Grid to be rendered like this to the page.

from:
     $(Html.Kendo().Grid...)

to:

```
 ${
     Html.Kendo().Grid...
      .Render();
  }
```

And see if the forms are generated. ALso you will need to either submit the forms programatically or add submit button.

Comment: Just adding ".Render()" to a Kendo Grid strangely that throws an error: SearchUserResultGrid.cshtml(6): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Make sure the brackets you have also changed the brackets to {} as in my example.

Comment: Closer. It now generates a string output that looks like it's writing the object name only: System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm { my link here } Instead of the form.